# ASK-CLI : unbale to link with AWS console account

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I've been trying to add my aws account to ask-cli so that i can directly deploy my lambda function.
whenever i try to clone or deploy it says,

```
No AWS credential setup for profile: [default]. 
Lambda clone skipped. CLI lambda functionalities can be enabled 
by running `ask init` again to add 'aws_profile' to ASK cli_config
```

even after following 'ask init' it has no effect.
I've added amazon developer account to ask-cli but unable to link with aws.
any help would be appreciated.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have installed aws-cli then plz run `aws-configure` and provide your id and secret key.

```
$ aws configure --profile user2
AWS Access Key ID [None]: AKIAI44QH8DHBEXAMPLE
AWS Secret Access Key [None]: je7MtGbClwBF/2Zp9Utk/h3yCo8nvbEXAMPLEKEY
Default region name [None]: us-east-1
Default output format [None]: text
```

otherwise create folder in home named `.aws` and add `credential` file in it. 
In that you can specify following format

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id=AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE
aws_secret_access_key=wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, this question has been already answered. But I want to add something.

If somehow, you did not setup the AWS credentials while setting up ASK profile, you can run below command to setup AWS credentials and link to an ASK profile.

```
ask init --aws-setup
```

Then, you will be prompted to enter your profile name, your access key, and your secret access key. Profile name will be **default** if you have not created multiple ASK profiles. After providing the credentials, you will not get the error mentioned in the question.